# Woocommerce - change order status from on-hold to pending payment

Tags: functions

I am trying to automate the change in order status from "on-hold" to "pending payment" once a product vendor has marked an order as fulfilled. Currently, the default status in "on-hold" when an order is created and only once the product is delivered must payment be required. Is it possible to update to the "pending" status after an action has been made?

Answer (score 1):

If you ever need to change the order status from php here is how to do it.

```
$order = new WC_Order($order_id);

if (!empty($order)) {
 $order->update_status( 'completed' );
}
```

Possible values: processing, on-hold, cancelled, completed

This is from woocommerce/includes/abstracts/abstract-wc-order.php

Answer (score 0):

a little late, but still hard to find...

**Possible values**

Based on https://www.bozzmedia.com/posts/get-know-woocommerce-status-definitions/

"**processing, on-hold, cancelled, completed, pending, failed, refunded**"

and that is supported in the WooCommerce Order class.. 
/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-order.php *- Around lines 108 or so.*

Assuming that you do not use a plugin capable of adding more.

Comment: how does it answer the question?

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_bacs_process_payment_order_status', function( $status = 'on_hold', $order = null ) {
return 'pending';
}, 10, 2 );
```

BUT if you use it, the status change could cause emails not being sent after an order comes in since it goes too quickly from 'on hold' to pending, and woocommerce does not send mails in 'pending'. I tried this, and after a few days mails were no longer sent out although it initially worked.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you just add see when you want to change status and add inside this function.

```
   add_action('woocommerce_order_status_changed','status_changed_processsing');
   function status_changed_processsing( $order_id, $checkout = null ) {
       global $woocommerce;
       $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
       if(your condition goes here){

           //assign statu to that order
           $order->status = 'pending';
        }
   }
```

Comment: Hi sonalip3, thank you for your response! I have added my conditions, but the code will still not work...    add_action('woocommerce_order_status_changed','status_changed_processsing');
   function status_changed_processsing( $order_id, $checkout = null ) {
       global $woocommerce;
       $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );       
       if( $order->status == 'on-hold'  && $order->fulfillment_status == 'fulfilled' ){

           //assign status to that order
           $order->status = 'pending';
        }
   }

Comment: Is it going inside if condition ,have you checked?

Comment: I have tested it with just using the 'on-hold' status condition and it works if I change the assigning status to the order by: $order->update_status('pending'). Can I ask you, I need to get the fulfillment_status from the woocommerce_order_itemmeta table, do you know how I can do this with using the same order_id?

Comment: I don't know which plugin you are using for 'fulfillment_status' so just try to print $order and check order object,mostly $order object saved that fulfilment_status. Just print this before condition: echo '<pre>';print_r($order);exit; . and try it will give you order object.

Comment: The plugin is the Woocommerce product vendor plugin, where the fulfillment_status is from. How do I see where the results are from printing to get the order object?

Comment: Is it paid plugin right?I dont have that .So just add this line: echo '<pre>';print_r($order);exit;  after this line:$order = new WC_Order( $order_id );and check by updating status.This is the object where 'fulfillment_status' should be added.

Comment: Yes it is a paid plugin. I have added this code, but am unable to see anything when I run it. How or where do I see the results of the print_r echo?

Comment: Have you check in database that your order id has 'fulfillment_status' in this table woocommerce_order_itemmeta?...Because table woocommerce_order_itemmeta is save the data of order items, not that perticular order.